# In Javascript is there a way to nest arrays eg. location>country>continent?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

For example lets say I have a list of locations. I want those locations in an array based on what country they are in but I also want those countries in an array based on continent.

So something like 
var regionName = [Europe[France, England[London, Birmingham], Spain]];

Thanks for any info and sorry I am so new at this!

Comment: Sure there's a way, but we're not here for coding, please share your attempts and we can help you. And if you're new you should read some documentation about arrays in JavaScript.

Comment: All I'm looking for is a point in the right direction. I'm incredibly new at this and trying to self learn.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can nest arrays. I usually work with an object that represents something in the real world and then have multiple arrays within it or make an array of objects, each with several pieces of information. Those object-oriented data structures are usually more useful than nested arrays but it really depends on what you're doing.

Here are some resources. If you could give me more info about your problem, I'd probably be able to help you more effectively:

http://www.elated.com/articles/nested-arrays-in-javascript/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Indexed_collections

For your specific question location>country>continent, you could look at this pseudocode for an idea:

let location = [place1, place2,...]

let country = [location1, location2, ...]

let continent = [country1, country2...]

The specifics don't matter. The key note in Javascript is that you specify the index of each array in sequence like so:

> console.log (continent[0][0][0]);

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks! That'll give me plenty to google now to help me on my way.

Comment: No worries! Try not to get discouraged. Everyone here means well despite the down votes. Self learning can be really hard. Where I live my library gives me free access to Lynda.com. Some schools have free access and you may have free access to your school library. I'm sure you have your own approach figured out though. If you have any more questions, don't hesitate to post them. : )